# If item is both in column A and B print in C

Tags: excel

Hello I have a really simple question. I have searched, and find lots of answers that compare matching cells in the same row or involve multiple rows, but nothing matching my really simple need.

I want to compare two entire columns. If a unique item appears anywhere in both column A and also in Column B, then compile a new list in column C. We are trying to give rewards to users who are participating in two different programs, but there are hundreds of IDs in both lists and the IDs are a couple dozen characters each, so sorting this manually is not practical.

Comment: Does the list change often, or do you just need to determine the unique values from the data you have this once? You can copy both columns to a separate sheet and combine them into a single column and then use a formula to count how many times each ID appears. Look at `COUNT` or `COUNTIF`. If you include a sample of your data in your post and some formulas you have tried, we can help more.

Comment: Each ID may appear multiple times in one of the columns. We have list A which is the unique cryptocurrency wallet addresses that are holding our token. We have list B which is the list of wallet addresses that have staked claims in our farming contract. Since B just pulls from a list of transactions, then if they participated multiple times then their wallet address would be in list B multiple times. I just want addresses that match both A and B to print in list C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is for Excel 365.

if the two datasets are *A2:A18* and *B2:B18*, then in **C2** enter:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A18,COUNTIF(B2:B18,A2:A18)))
```

For example:

[image]

**REFERENCE:**

[Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formula/filter-to-extract-matching-values)